# Material EditText "password_toggle" Icon Visible without focus/data - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to hide this Icon of `password_toggle` when `EditText` is Blank. Only show this icon when Any data inside this.

**Like:  `clear_text` icon work inside Name Section.**

[image: Here Blank editText showing icon]

I am using `app:endIconMode="password_toggle"` inside `TextInputLayout`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
            android:hint="Password">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edittextPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using a [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher).

If you use [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx) via `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0"`

You will get access to a convenient extension method you can use like this:

```
edittextPassword.doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after -> 
    // if text is blank, hide end icon,
    // otherwise, show password toggle
}
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/widget/package-summary#(android.widget.TextView).doOnTextChanged(kotlin.Function4)

Answer (score 0):

1- put this line on create()

binding.etPasswordLayout.isPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled = false

2- setText Watcher like this

```
   binding.edtPassword.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
   override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, 
    i1: Int, i2: Int) {
            binding.etPasswordLayout.isPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled = 
              true
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
        binding.etPasswordLayout.isPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled = false
     }
      })
```